# how to position two elements left and right

Tags: customization, css, html

In my wordpress theme I am trying to add a border at the bottom of the posts. On top of the border I want a comments link at the left and a share link at the right. I have tried multiple times to get it to look how I want it, but it never works. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could achieve this? Thanks in advance. I have attached a picture of what it looks like now and how I want it to look along with my code.

How it looks now...
[image]

how I want it to look...
[image]

how it looks with suggestions (updated)...
[image]
single.php

```html
<?php
get_header();
the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); 
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="post">
    
<?php wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?>    
    <div class="post-info">    
    <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <h2 class="post-date"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', 'Location: ', ', ', ' • ' ));?><?php the_date('F m, Y'); ?></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <div class="post-footer"><h1 class="post-footer-comment"><?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></h1><h2 class="share">share</h2><?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons-post' ); ?></div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile;
else :
echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;
get_footer();
 
?>
```

and my css

```html
 .post-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    margin:40px 100px 0 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: justify;
max-width:1865px;
}
.post-footer-comment {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.post-footer-comment a:hover {
    color:#555555;
}
.share-buttons-post {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.share {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

comments.php

```html
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h4 class="comments-title">Post a Comment</h4>
    <ol class="comment-list">
<?php wp_list_comments('callback=custom_comments');?>
 </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    $comments_args = array(
  'id_form'           => 'commentform',
  'class_form'      => 'comment-form',
  'id_submit'         => 'submit',
  'class_submit'      => 'submit',
  'name_submit'       => 'submit',
  'title_reply'       => __( 'Join the Conversation' ),
  'title_reply_to'    => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s' ),
  'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Cancel reply' ),
  'label_submit'      => __( 'Post Comment' ),
  'format'            => 'xhtml',        


  'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' .
    sprintf(
      __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
      wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' .
    sprintf(
    __( ' <a href="</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account"></a>' ),
      admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
      $user_identity,
      wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' .
    __( '' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) .
    '</p>',
        
        
 'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) . '</label> ' .
    ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
    '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

  'url' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'domainreference' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
    '" size="30" /></p>',          

 
        




);
    comment_form($comments_args);
?>
```

functions.php

```html
<?php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
    function learningWordPress_resources() {
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    }
 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');
     
//Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {
 
var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
global $wp_query;
$indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
$class_names = $value = '';
$classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
/* Add active class */
if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
$classes[] = 'active';
unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
}
/* Check for children */
$children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
if (!empty($children)) {
$classes[] = 'has-sub';
}
$class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';
$id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
$id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
$attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</span></a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;
$output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$output .= "</li>\n";
}
}
 
 
// Add Widget Areas
function ourWidgetsInit() {
     
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
     
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 1',
        'id' => 'footer1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
     
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 2',
        'id' => 'footer2',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
     
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 3',
        'id' => 'footer3',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
     
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Footer Area 4',
        'id' => 'footer4',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
     
}
 
add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit');

// Theme setup
function learningWordpress_setup() {
// Navigation Menus    
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu'),
    'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));

// Add featured image support
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('medium-thumbnail', 446, 345, true);
    add_image_size('large-thumbnail', 1386, 595, true);
    add_image_size('popular-posts', 256, 256, true);
        add_image_size('banner-image', 5555,2500, true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'learningWordpress_setup');
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function location() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Locations',
        'singular_name'              => 'Location',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Location',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
        'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
        'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
        'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
        'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'location', 0 );
// Carousel
function carousel_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/effects.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carousel_scripts' );
// Custom control for carousel category
 
if (class_exists('WP_Customize_Control')) {
    class WP_Customize_Category_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
 
        public function render_content() {
   
            $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( 
                array(
                    'name'              => '_customize-dropdown-category-' . $this->id,
                    'echo'              => 0,
                    'show_option_none'  => __( '&mdash; Select &mdash;' ),
                    'option_none_value' => '0',
                    'selected'          => $this->value(),
                     
                )
            );
 
            $dropdown = str_replace( '<select', '<select ' . $this->get_link(), $dropdown );
  
            printf(
                '<label class="customize-control-select"><span class="customize-control-title">%s</span> %s</label>',
                $this->label,
                $dropdown
            );
        }
    }
}
 
// Register slider customizer section 
 
add_action( 'customize_register' , 'carousel_options' );
 
function carousel_options( $wp_customize ) {
 
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'carousel_section',
    array(
        'title'     => 'Carousel settings',
        'priority'  => 202,
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
    )
);
 
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'carousel_setting',
     array(
    'default'   => '',
  )
);
 
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_category_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'carousel_category',
        array(
            'label'    => 'Category',
            'settings' => 'carousel_setting',
            'section'  => 'carousel_section'
        )
    )
);
 
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'count_setting',
     array(
    'default'   => '6',
 
  )
);
 
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'carousel_count',
        array(
            'label'          => __( 'Number of posts', 'theme_name' ),
            'section'        => 'carousel_section',
            'settings'       => 'count_setting',
            'type'           => 'text', 
        )
    )
);
 
}
//MORE COMMENTS
/**
 * Return the default comment form fields.
 *  Customize comment form default fields.
 * Move the comment_field below the author, email, and url fields.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields( $fields ) {
    $commenter     = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $user          = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_identity = $user->exists() ? $user->display_name : '';
    $req           = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req      = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields = [
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required"></span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="245"' . $aria_req . $html_req . ' /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required"></span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="email"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="100" aria-describedby="email-notes"' . $aria_req . $html_req  . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( '', 'textdomain'  ) . '</label> ' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" ' . ( $html5 ? 'type="url"' : 'type="text"' ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" maxlength="200" /></p>',
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( '', 'noun', 'textdomain' ) . '</label> <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p>',
    ];

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields' );

/**
 * Remove the original comment field because we've added it to the default fields
 * using wpse250243_comment_form_default_fields(). If we don't do this, the comment
 * field will appear twice.
 */
function wpse250243_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
    if ( isset( $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] ) ) {
        $defaults[ 'comment_field' ] = '';
    }

    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse250243_comment_form_defaults', 10, 1 );
//COMMENTS
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse_62742_comment_placeholders' );

/**
 * Change default fields, add placeholder and change type attributes.
 *
 * @param  array $fields
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_62742_comment_placeholders( $fields )
{
    $fields['author'] = str_replace(
        '<input',
        '<input placeholder="'
        /* Replace 'theme_text_domain' with your theme’s text domain.
         * I use _x() here to make your translators life easier. :)
         * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x
         */
            . _x(
                'Name',
                'comment form placeholder',
                'theme_text_domain'
                )
            . '"',
        $fields['author']
    );
    $fields['email'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="email" name="email" type="text"',
        /* We use a proper type attribute to make use of the browser’s
         * validation, and to get the matching keyboard on smartphones.
         */
        '<input type="email" placeholder="Email"  id="email" name="email"',
        $fields['email']
    );
    $fields['url'] = str_replace(
        '<input id="url" name="url" type="text"',
        // Again: a better 'type' attribute value.
        '<input placeholder="Website" id="url" name="url" type="url"',
        $fields['url']
    );

    

    return $fields;
}
//Comments Continued
if ( get_option ('thread_comments') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
}
//Comments
function custom_comments ($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
  <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
      <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
          <header class="comment-author-vcard">
              
              
              <?php printf (__('<cite_class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says"></span>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
    </header>
          

          
          <div class="comment-meta"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID )) ?>"></a></div>
              
              <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text() ?></div>
              
          <div class="comment-time"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'), '   ', ' ') ?><?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ))) ?></div>                           
          
           
          
          <div class="reply">
              
          </div>
      </div>
          <?php
}
//New Menus
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'new-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu Secondary' ),
      'another-menu' => __( 'Another Menu' ),
      'an-extra-menu' => __( 'An Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
// Wordpress
function load_fonts() {
            wp_register_style('et-googleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=David+Libre|Crimson+Text|Questrial|Montserrat|Catamaran|Pathway+Gothic+One|PT+Serif|Days+One|Lato:300|Work+Sans:400,500,600,700');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts');
        }
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
// Popular Posts
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) { 
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true); 
if($count==''){ 
$count = 0; 
delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key); 
add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, 0); 
}else{ 
$count++; 
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count); 
} 
} 
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching 
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) { 
if ( !is_single() ) return; 
if ( empty ( $post_id) ) { 
global $post; 
$post_id = $post->ID; 
} 
wpb_set_post_views($post_id); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're trying to right-align the share buttons.

Try changing this part:

```
<h2 class="share">share</h2><?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons-post' ); ?>
```

to this:

```
<div class="share"><span>share</span> <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons-post' ); ?></div>
```

**EDIT** based on further comments: to now put the footer line below the comments / share information, add this to the `.post-footer` CSS:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

And to move the word 'share' down slightly, use the updated `<div class="share">` line above, and then this CSS should do it:

```
.share span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: I added a picture to my original question of how it looks now. Although it positioned the share buttons to the right, the border is now on top (and also the share element is slightly above the comments element)

Comment: That edited answer worked great. The share buttons are aligned right now. I have one last problem. How can I get the comments link to start at the border-bottom (the share buttons align with the end of the line, I want the comments to align with the beginning of the line) I edited question with new picture.

Comment: @user6738171 Not sure what's adding the left indent. Perhaps some `<h1>` CSS? Try making it a `div` instead: `<div class="post-footer-comment"><?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>`

Comment: Unfortunately, making the h1 a div did not work. The indent is still there.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML that gets outputted around the comments?

Comment: I added in my comments.php and functions.php